# Bootstrap. Мобильные устройства

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Всем привет. Не думал, что придется сюда обращаться. Есть проблема.
Почему-то Bootstrap некорректно работает на мобильных устройствах.
Если подробнее, то **col-lg-..** "смешивается" с **col-xl-..**.

При любом значении **xl**, оно не срабатывает на мобильных устройствах. Оно наоборот меняет элемент в ПК-версии. Т.е. **col-lg-..** и **col-xl..** создают одно и то же.

Версия Bootstrap: **4.2.1.**

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: желательно бы кусок кода привести. Лучше прямо в вопросе

Comment: Допустим, этот `div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-12 col-xl-6">Text</div>
        <div class="col col-lg-12 col-xl-6">Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Но я не про конкретный кусок кода. Весь код так работает. XL не работает. Не пойму, почему.

Comment: видимо вы перепутали `xl` (eXtra Large) и `xs` (eXtra Small). `xl` - это для сверхбольших экранов, а не для мобильных

Comment: Честно говоря, я думал, что bootstrap 4 не поддерживает XS. И в подсказках не высвечивалось. Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: `$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;`